# Proving these terms converges

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, solution-verification

Let $X$ a random variable with values in $\mathbb{N}^*$, assume X has a finite mathematical expected value $E[X] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty kP(X=k) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty P(X > k) - \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} nP(X > n)$

i need to prove that $(nP(X > n))_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*}$ converges to 0, and $\sum_{k=0}^\infty P(X > k)$ converges.
so here is my idea since $$\sum_{k=0}^n kP(X=k) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} P(X > k) - nP(X > n) $$ $$\iff 0 \leq nP(X > n) \leq n$$ if we let $a_n = nP(X > n)$ then
$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{n+1}{n} \frac{P(X > n+1)}{P(X > n+1) + P(X= n+1)} < 1 \iff a_{n+1} < a_n$ thus $ \sum_{n \geq 1} (a_n)$ is a converging series  thus $a_n \rightarrow 0$, is it better now?

Comment: Why is $\sum a_n<\infty$?

Comment: im really confused on how i got that too, i just feel like its true @geetha290krm

Comment: If $\mathbf{P}(X=k)=\frac{1}{k^2}-\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}$, then $X$ has finite expectation but $a_k=k\mathbf{P}(X>k)=\frac{k}{(k+1)^2}$ is not summable.

Comment: *Hint.* Note that $$n\mathbf{P}(X>n)=\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} n\mathbf{P}(X=k)\leq \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} k \mathbf{P}(X=k). $$ Can you show that this bound converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$? (*Remark.* This is essentially what geetha290krm suggested in the answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$nP(X>n)\leq E(1_{X>n}X) \to 0$ by Dominated Convergence Theorem.